# External css that contain <a href> styling

Tags: html, css, external

I want to make an external CSS that contain `<a href>` styling, but don't know how to do it. I've tried

```
a{
  color:#F0F8FF;
  background-color:transparent;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

but my HTML won't be that color when I linked that in my HTML
I linked that like this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="style.css">`
the name of the CSS is style.css by the way

Comment: Did you verify the css file is being loaded by looking at it in the network panel?

Comment: Is the location of the html file where you have this link and the css file in the same directory or they are in different directories?

Answer (score 0):

The correct value for the **type** argument should be `text/css` ! (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_type.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "type="css""

should work fine.
Also, is the a href tag inside of an element? If you have something like

```
<div id="sidenav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href...>
```

then your CSS should read

```
#sidenav a {text-decoration: none;
            color:#FFFFFF;
```

Comment: <div id="sidenav">
  <ul>
   <li><a
I'm not sure why this didn't post the first time, but this was the html example

Answer (score 0):

Hi please add type text

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Comment: don't just write the code, kindly also give some explanation so that the OP understands what is wrong with his code